# Where to get IKEA Premiar sized canvas prints for the same rate?

Tags: digital, printing, canvas

IKEA sells high quality canvas prints ([PREMIAR series](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/20114901/)) for $130. These prints are 78" * 55". Where can I get similar sized canvas prints for my custom photo for the same price? I don't think anyone prints such huge size canvas just for 130 bucks?

Comment: Are you interested in producing the quantity that Ikea probably does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IKEA is a multinational retailer that also happens to be the world's largest furniture seller. Considering that it sells upwards of 28BB/yr, they have considerable buying power and marketplace presence. It is not reasonable to believe that a consumer or even a small business could obtain similar pricing to such a large corporation.

For comparison, a popular consumer canvas lab CanvasOnDemand does make 78"x55" gallery wraps that run between $585-664(without a coupon right now). Most popular professional labs do not offer canvas wraps that are larger then about 30"-40" per side. You will have a hard time even finding many options for such a large canvas print.

To give you an idea of the absolute lowest priced canvas wraps I've seen as of recently, the lab I have in mind offers 32"x48" wraps for $99.99 which I consider to be an absolute steal of a price. I consider it to be so low, that I won't even share the "secret lab" :)

Finally, I would ask yourself if you even have images that can stand up to being printed that large. Maybe you do, but do keep in mind that a print from even a midrange DSLR might be challenged if the printer is a quality one.

Overall, if you represent a big enough corporation that can demand these types of prices similar to IKEA - you aren't going to be looking for posted price sheets, you will be working on contracts and negociated deals. If you are a small business owner or consumer, I believe that you simply won't find that price for a canvas(and probably not even for a decent print).

Comment: Thanks. I do understand that only IKEA like companies can afford it. I was just curious to know more about it.

Comment: You don't need to use any market bully leverage; you simply need to be able to afford the >$10K print job setup and tooling to make the wrap "brainless", and you, too, can get prints that size at, say, $50-60 a pop. Offset printing is cheap after the setup (separations, screening, plate production, alignment, etc.). If you only want one print, or even a small run, then even the ridiculously large price of inkjet ink begins to look tiny in comparison.